# How to bevel corners and edges a different amount?

Tags: bevel

I'd like to bevel the corners of my cube more than the edges of my cube.  Any way to achieve this?  Please see image of the two effects that I'd like to combine.

[image: Edge vs corner bevel]

Comment: what object are you trying to create? (I don't think that you can bevel an "angle")

Comment: I'm making dice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to round more the edges.

So you can inset individually the faces of a cube:

[image]

and add a subdivision surface:

[image]

Comment: Oh that's just perfect!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two *Bevel modifiers* with different offset.
Just set the first one to affect *Only Vertices*.

[image]

Comment: Ah I tried that, but I can't bevel the edges as much as I want using that technique.

Comment: @RobertSeber This is a limitation of the bevel modifier in Blender. It is planned to add a sliding effect once the bevel get to the overlap threshold, but there is no way to know when or if it will be added.